# xml.Unmarshal unsupported type struct

Tags: go, serialization, reflection

I'm getting an error where I cannot xml.Marshal a struct made at runtime with reflect.

It is giving me the following error:

```
xml: unsupported type: struct { ... }
```

Here is my go-playground [link](https://go.dev/play/p/6Lr57InWe8a).

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?
What am I missing about the implementation?
It works fine for JSON and YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.20.3#Marshal

> The name for the XML elements is taken from, in order of preference:
>
> - the tag on the XMLName field, if the data is a struct
> - the value of the XMLName field of type Name
> - the tag of the struct field used to obtain the data
> - the name of the struct field used to obtain the data
> - the name of the marshaled type

Your *root* struct is *unnamed* and has *no `XMLName` field*, therefore the XML marshaler is unable to resolve the root element's name. If you rename the `Person xml.Name` field to `XMLName` then to serializer works.

https://go.dev/play/p/gRH3Y-PUxl8